# How to select column if string is in column name

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, data-science

so I have a dict of dataframes with many columns. I want to selected all the columns that have the string 'important' in them.
So some of the frames may have important_0 or important_9_0 as their column name. How can I select them and put them into their own new dictionary with all the values each columns contains.

Comment: kindly provide sample data with expected output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```py
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame(columns=['a', 'b', 'important_c'])
selected_cols = [c for c in df.columns if c.startswith('important_')]
print(selected_cols)
# ['important_c']

dict_df = { x: pd.DataFrame(columns=['a', 'b', 'important_c']) for x in range(3) }
new_dict = { x: dict_df[x][[c for c in dict_df[x].columns if c.startswith('important_')]] for x in dict_df }
```

Answer (score 1):

```
important_columns = [x for x in df.columns if 'important' in x]
#changing your dataframe by remaining columns that you need
df = df[important_columns]
```